# matlab command doesn't exist

Tags: matlab, shell, command

I'm a new user of shell and I would like to run my matlab code from another computer using SSH.

The computer has Matlab installed but here is what I have when I type matlab in the terminal :

```
 XXX:Desktop YYY$ matlab
-bash: matlab: command not found
```

The idea would be to run as shown on the following code - which is working if runned on Matlab.

```
XXX:Desktop YYY$ ls
matlabSSHtest.m
XXX:Desktop hugpf875$ matlab matlabSSHtest.m
```

Comment: Don't know bash, but my bet would be that you need to specify the full path. Or add the matlab location to some default search path.

Comment: If you have `sudo` access to it, try this to locate the path to matlab executable - `sudo find / -name matlab -executable -type f`. Then add it to `PATH` by this `PATH=$PATH:path_to_matlab`. Then you can start `MATLAB` by typing `matlab` on the terminal.

Comment: Try `locate matlab` to see where it's installed. Then add its directory to your PATH: in your ~/.profile, add the line `PATH="$PATH:/path/where/matlab/is/installed"`

Comment: @glennjackman and also `source ~/.profile`

Comment: I believe the default install dir on Linux is `/usr/local/matlab/R20XX`. Otherwise: do a `find` like Divakar suggested (unless you have some countermeasures in place, `locate` is perpetually out of date).